# How to display which key holds the most number of values and the corresponding total?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with four keys and would like to display which key has the most elements or values in them and how many values is stored.

my dictionary looks like this

```
{'rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'trolley': [5, 10, 15, 25, 30], 'ward': [0, 12, 10, 8, 3], 'patients': [200, 100, 1000, 500, 375]
```

in the variable explorer and my excel file I can see the key or column "patients" has the most amount of total values with 220 (so 220 rows in excel) and the smallest amount of total values is the "trolley" key/column with 64 (64 rows in excel file)

I have tried multiple resources online which suggest the use of the following below

```
print("Highest key is:", max(hosp,key=hosp.get), "with total", max(hosp.values()))
```

```
print("Highest key is:", min(hosp,key=hosp.get), "with total", min(hosp.values()))
```

all this does for me is print the key that has the highest individual value so e.g. "patients" and then prints the entire "patients" key with all the individual values i.e. "[200, 100, 1000, 500, 375]"

but I want it to show which key has the most and which key has the least elements/rows in it, which should result in "patients with 220 values" as it has 220 entries or rows from the excel file. and the min should show "trolley with 64 values"

also for the purpose of this I need to accomplish this without any modules so I cannot import anything

Comment: From the excel file I am using, I have added the contents of the file into my dictionary. 220 is the total amount of rows for the patient column in the excel file so the 'patients' key in the dictionary has 220 individual values.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I interpret it wrong. Till now, you have been able to execute the code you have provided, with an exception that the values being printed is the whole list and not the maximum value among the list.

Secondly, you have mentioned that you are trying to display the amount of rows rather than the maximum value.

`len` function can help you achieve it. It returns the length of an iterable.

I am assuming here, that the list you have displayed is only a extract from the excel file.

```py
print("Highest key is:", max(hosp,key=hosp.get), "with total", len(max(hosp.values())))
```

From the code you have provided, the suitable output is below:

> Highest key is: patients with total 5

Comment: ye list I have displayed is only a small extract from the excel file. the len part of your answer displays the number of values correct for the key it picked, but for some reason will not show the correct key.

Comment: Can you upload the updated version of your code? Because from my perspective, it is working fine.